# Difference between Ethermint and Burrow

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, ethereum, hyperledger-burrow

What is the difference between Ethermint and Hyperledger Burrow? Both work on Tendermint Proof of Stake Consensus and use EVM state machine.

Answer (score 0):

They both support EVM, but are separate implementations of EVM. Hyperledger Burrow is part of The Linux Foundation's Hyperledger blockchain consortium.